# Pass string to function taking Read trait

Tags: file-io, rust

I want to call this function in a 3rd party library ([xmltree-rs](https://github.com/eminence/xmltree-rs)):

```
pub fn parse<R: Read>(r: R) -> Element {
```

The expected use case is to give it a file, like so:

```
let e: Element = Element::parse(File::open("tests/data/01.xml").unwrap());
```

However I have a `String` which I want to pass, vaguely like this:

```
xmltree::Element::parse("<example>blah</example>".to_owned());
```

However this, of course, gives an error:

```
error: the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for the type `collections::string::String` [E0277]
```

How would I do this, short of writing a temporary file? (e.g in Python I would use the [StringIO module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO) to wrap the string in a file-like object)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To find out what implements a trait, go to [the bottom of the page for that trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#implementors).

In this case, the most promising looking implementers are `&'a [u8]` and `Cursor<Vec<u8>>`.

You can obtain a `&[u8]` from a `&str` or `String` by calling [`as_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes), taking note of automatic dereferencing and [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) on `String`s. Alternatively, you could use a byte literal if you are only using the ASCII subset.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing an answer that points back to the Rust docs and thus provides a model for how to answer the question unaided in future.

Comment: In some situations (such as dependency injection), you cannot use references (i.e. `&`). In that case, use `Cursor`. You can create a new cursor by `Cursor::new(s.into_bytes())`. In Rust 1.63.0 or later, you can also use `VecDeque<u8>` created by `VecDeque::from(s.into_bytes())`.